# Есть соответствующие переменные с них хочу создать функцию online/offline юзер

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть переменные типа :
`$uid` - ID пользователя
`$user_role` - Роль пользователя
и ф-ция `is_user_logged_in();` который возвращает 0 или 1 при выходе и входа пользователя. Как примерно реализовать фукнцию онлайн оффлайн юзеров. Только с одним ролем нужно такое сделать, если в `$user_role` находиться значение `lawyers`когда данный пользователь зашел на сайт. Можно пример с кукисами... Вопрос  "куда копать"?

Comment: из описания не очень понятно, что именно вам необходимо сделать: добавить индикатор для текущего пользователя или для карточки произвольного пользователя, посчитать общее число пользователей на сайте или что-то ещё?

Comment: Индикатор онлайн/оффлайн хочу сделать.

Comment: Вот тут, похоже, то, что вам нужно: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/34429/how-to-check-if-a-user-not-current-user-is-logged-in

Comment: Попробывал все варианты, ниче не получается( может косячу где-то...но понять слсожно где, если у кого есть способ по проще опишите)